# WMI Service Host using a high amount, 10-20% CPU a lot of the time

Tags: windows-10, cpu, event-viewer, wmi

On my Windows 10 laptop, the application WMI Service Host is using a considerable amount of CPU time and spinning the fans up. This is not normal operation. WMI should be called somewhat rarely. I can't find help online, since most of the articles/answers point to checking the errors in Event Log under Applications and Service Logs | Microsoft | Windows | WMI Activity and looking for the process ID causing these errors. But in my case it seems that the activity is not causing errors, so I can't solve the issue this way. [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/wmi-provider-host-high-cpu-usage-and-laptop/44cb3953-a883-404a-a94f-ee4f363d3a4b?auth=1) is one forum post recommending this fix. How can I see the access logs, not the error logs?

Comment: Try removing any and all Anti Virus except Windows Defender.  Restart and test.  Are you using the very latest version of Windows 10

Comment: @John This question is for people who want to find the actual reason why the process is using so much resources, and to not blindly try different solutions. I gave the way to check access logs below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to enable access logs is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/tracing-wmi-activity). I will outline the process here.

1. Again, go to the same path in Event Viewer: Applications and Service Logs | Microsoft | Windows | WMI Activity (for me it was WMI-Activity).
2. Expand the folder
3. Open the right-click (context) menu for Trace.
4. Click Properties and enable logging by checking the box. Now you can see access logs under Tracing.
5. Click on a log in the center view and pay attention to the value of ClientProcessId. Go through the access logs and take note of those IDs.
6. Open Task Manager, and go to the Details tab. click on PID to sort by the Process ID, and scroll to find a match for the offending process using the ID noted earlier. Now you should consider whether this application's functions are important enough to warrant the CPU use, or investigate further if the use of CPU seems unnecessary for what the program is doing.

You can now disable the access logs. The default maximum size for the logs is about 1 MB, so it is not absolutely necessary.

For me this was a huge relief, since I could easily figure out the common denominator in the access logs, which was in my case RescueTime, a time logging application. I wasn't really using it anymore, so I uninstalled it. Wonderful silence.

Comment: I don't have "WMI-Activity" folder under "Windows". What do I do?

Comment: @alexkovelsky Which version of Windows are you using? Can you show a screenshot of the logs hierarchy?

Comment: It was Windows 7 on some old computer, and I first tried to dump all logs to file via CMD, interestingly "CliendProcessId" was all the time 0 for all entries. After that I just went brutal way, looked for processes using CPU and deleted few folders from "Program Files", and CPU usage dropped. Most probably it was "Roxio" folder which I deleted that fixed the issue.